# How does `<$` function work in the Functor class?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, function-composition, pointfree

In the Functor class definition we have the `<$` function defined as:

```
class  Functor f  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

    (<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
    (<$)        =  fmap . const
```

The `const` function has the definition:

```
const                   :: a -> b -> a
const x _               =  x
```

I know that the `<$` function is equivalent to:

```
\x -> fmap (const x)
```

How does `fmap . const` equate to the lambda expression above? My understanding of function composition is that output type of `const` should match the input type of `fmap`, but the input type of `fmap` is the function `(a -> b)` not `a` which is what the `const` function outputs.

Comment: Your question inspired me to check the definition of `<$` for `Data.Map`. It will be considerably faster in the next release. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer does a good job of addressing the question, "How does `fmap . const` equate to the lambda expression above?", so I want to address a different part:

> My understanding of function composition is that output type of `const` should match the input type of `fmap`, but the input type of `fmap` is the function `(a -> b)` not `a` which is what the `const` function outputs.

In this answer, I will argue that the output type of `const` is indeed a function as needed by `fmap`.

Let's rewrite the types of `fmap` and `const`, using separate type variables in each to avoid confusion:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
const :: c -> (d -> c)
```

Now, one must ask: what is the output type of `const`? In your question, you posit that the output type is `c` (after correcting for type variable renaming as above). But in fact this is a slight misunderstanding; the true output type is `d -> c`!

The output of `const` is actually a function. Now, as you say, its output must match the input of `fmap`. With our naming above, this means we must choose to satisfy the equation `d ~ a` (read: type `d` and type `a` are the same type) and satisfy `c ~ b`. Then we will have:

```
const        :: b -> (a -> b)
fmap         ::      (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
fmap . const :: b             -> (f a -> f b)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. So my comment above that a partially applied function was being fmap'ed to the functor is not correct. It was actually a function of (d -> c) that was being applied.

Answer (score 5):

Note that:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

(see the [definition of `(.)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#.)) so,

```
(fmap . const) x = fmap (const x)
```

**Original Answer**

For concreteness, let's use the IO functor.

`fmap f` work on an IO-computation by applying `f` to the result of the computation.

E.g. - `getContents` is an `IO String`, and `length` is a function on Strings, so we can fmap length on getContents:

```
getContents              :: IO String
length                   ::    String -> Int
fmap length getContents  ::              IO Int
```

When run this would read all of standard input, take the length of the input, and return it (as an IO-action).

Now, `const z` is a function which ignores its argument and always returns `z`. So if I were to `fmap (const 'w')` on `getContents` I would have:

```
getContents                   :: IO String
const 'w'                     ::    String -> Char
fmap (const 'w') getContents  ::              IO Char
```

When executed, this would first read in all of standard input, then discard that input and return the character 'w'.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But what I want to know is how the composition is equivalent to the lambda expression.

Comment: So in effect, `const x` is a partially applied function which gets `fmap`ed to any functor that is passed to it in this case.

Comment: You can always `fmap (const x)` onto a functor computation of any type because `const x` ignores its argument. A good example is `void`: [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void)

Comment: Would you agree that `fmap` is taking a partially applied function `const x`? I just want to confirm my thinking

Comment: `const x` is a partially applied function, but that is not a requirement for use with fmap.

Comment: @Mika'il `const x` <s>is</s> defines a function, resulting from `const` being applied to `x`. But there's no requirement for actual function to be created. I suspect you think in terms of concrete implementation (where actual function objects get partially applied to stuff creating other actual function objects in memory). Don't. `const x` can be compiled out completely *before* a program runs.